# Showing unique data in dropdown PHP mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

i have a database in mySql. i'm showing one of it's field in a drop down list.this field contains rows that may contain repeated data. e.g

- bread;milk;butter;bread;milk
- ginger;tomatoes;ginger;butter
- cupcake;bread

now i want this data to be shown in drop down list as

- bread
- milk
- butter
- ginger
- tomatoes
- cupcake

distinct keyword wont work here i guess because i want to read data from everyrow and within the row as well and display it uniquely. we'd have to break the data and display it ..!!

thanks for your support ...

Comment: Why don't you get `DISTINCT` data from database?

Comment: You should add the code you have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number of answer say `use distinct` which is pointless here because the value of column is like `"bread;milk;butter;bread;milk"`

split the string by `;` and insert them in array using the same key and value

```
$distinctArray="";

$data[]= explode(";",$str);
foreach($data as $string){
  $distinctArray[string]=$string;
}
```

This array would replace the duplicates and would return 1 mapping.

Comment: this is the code i'm using for fetching entire data from db to dropdown of that specific column. can u edit your code according to this ? 

`$namequery="SELECT expanseType FROM excel12"; `

`$nameresult=mysql_query($namequery) or die ("Query to get data from table failed: ".mysql_error());`
`while ($namerow=mysql_fetch_array($nameresult)) {
    $nameTitle=$namerow["expanseType"];`
`echo "<option >
                   $nameTitle
                </option>" ;}`

Comment: @babar... in my code $str has the value of the column

Comment: tell me what to echo to get the result ?

Answer (score 0):

Use DISTINCT while querying to database

```
SELECT DISTINCT Field FROM table
```

Comment: each row is like "bread;milk;butter;bread;milk"

Comment: each entry is like "bread;milk;butter;bread;milk" ..distinct is pointless here

Comment: then you have to cut the string from ";" it will convert to array and then you have to use array_unique() function to get distinct values

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_array_unique

have a look

Answer (score 0):

Use [`explode`](http://php.net/explode), [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).  Something like the following:

```
$result = array();
while($namerow = mysql_fetch_array($nameresult)) {
    $result = array_merge($result, explode($namerow["expanseType"], ";"));
}
$result = array_unique($result);
foreach($result as $option) {
    echo "<option>$option</option>";
}
```

Comment: this is the code i'm using that shows column name and other info. can u edit your code according to this ? 

`$namequery="SELECT expanseType FROM excel12"; `

`$nameresult=mysql_query($namequery) or die ("Query to get data from table failed: ".mysql_error());`
`while ($namerow=mysql_fetch_array($nameresult)) {
    $nameTitle=$namerow["expanseType"];`
`echo "<option >
                   $nameTitle
                </option>" ;}`

Comment: Did it.  Give that a try.

Comment: nope it's not working .. it's just showing 1 option i.e 
;
in dropdown

Comment: Can you provide the code you're using in a PHP/MySQL fiddle?  http://phpfiddle.org/

Comment: http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=\n\n\n\n<label >Select ExpenseType %2526nbsp;%2526nbsp;%2526nbsp;%2526nbsp;%2526nbsp;%2526nbsp;%2526nbsp;%2526nbsp;</label>\n <select id="exptype" name="expense" >\n <option style="display:none;">...</option>\n <option selected="selected">ALL</option>\n\n <?php\n $namequery=

Comment: "SELECT expanseType FROM exc";\n $nameresult=mysql_query($namequery) or die ("Query to get data from table failed: ".mysql_error());\n $result = array();\n\t\t\t\twhile($namerow = mysql_fetch_array($nameresult))\n\t\t\t\t {\n \t\t\t\t\t $result = array_merge($result, explode($namerow["expanseType"], ";"));\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t$result = array_unique($result);\n\t\tforeach($result as $option)\n\t\t \t{\n \techo "<option>$option</option>";\n\t\t\t}\n}\n?>\n

Comment: merge the links and enter

Answer (score 0):

## If you want to filter Duplicate values in the Query itself (recommended):

### You can use

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`<column_name>`) FROM `<table_name>`;
```

## If you want to filter it only at the script level:

### You can use

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $items[] = $row['column_name'];
}
$items = array_unique($items);
```